# Azure Function Build Pipelines Fails when Unit Test Project references the Function project

Tags: azure-devops, continuous-integration, azure-functions

I am using Visual Studio 2019 Community Edition and I have a multi-tier solution. Below is a screenshot of that.

Please note, it's a sample project to replicate a production solution, so, namings probably are not really important here.

[image]

**Project specifications:** (all `netcoreapp3.1`)

1. Sample.AzureFunction.Api - Target Framework: `netcoreapp3.1`and Azure Function version: `3.0.7`
2. { Application, Model, ClassLibrary1, and ClassLibrary2 } - Target Framework: `netcoreapp3.1` and all are `.netcore class library' projects.
3. ApiTests - Target Framework: `netcoreapp3.1`

**The Problem**

The Azure Build Pipeline fails when there is a reference from the `ApiTest` project to the `Sample.AzureFunction.Api`. If I remove the project reference, the build continues to be green. Here is a screenshot from the build errors when the `build` step is running in the pipeline.

Basically, all the errors are complaining about not finding some dlls. For example, `CSC : error CS0006: Metadata file 'D:\a\1\s\publish_output\Application.dll' could not be found [D:\a\1\s\Sample.AzureFunction.Api\Tests\ApiTests\ApiTests.csproj]`

[image]

**Few Notes:**

1. The `build` step in the pipeline is `.net core` added automatically by Azure DevOps.
2. I don't have a dedicated Agent and I use the `Azure Pipelines` that comes by default when creating a new CI.
3. Agent specification is `windows-2019`

I used the classic view to create the pipeline (no YAML) but I could grab the following YAML from the generated steps by clicking on each of them and copying the YAML:

[image]

I've spent a day on resolving this issue and I'm running out of ideas now. Any thoughts would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you show your pipeline definition? Do you have the same when you run it locally?

Comment: I just put that within the question now and yes it's basically the same thing - quite straightforward actually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you remove `--output` argument your build will succeeded.

It looks like your folder `publish_output` was cleared before compiling test project. Thus it can't find these dlls there.

Furthermore, you don't need rather to publish as an artifact all dlls. Please use publish command to create artifact for code which is going to be deployed:

```yaml
- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  inputs:
    command: publish
    publishWebProjects: True
    arguments: '--configuration $(BuildConfiguration) --output $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
    zipAfterPublish: True

# this code takes all the files in $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory) and uploads them as an artifact of your build.
- task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
  inputs:
    pathtoPublish: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)' 
    artifactName: 'myWebsiteName'
```

I listed `publish_output` folder after running your original pipeline and you can find there these files:

```
Application.deps.json
ClassLibrary1.deps.json
Function1
Sample.AzureFunction.Api.deps.json
bin
host.json
```

Comment: Thanks for this. Just a bit of confusion for me here - are you actually suggesting to use the `publish` command instead of the `build` command in the build step of the pipeline?

Comment: Not instead. After running unit tests you should run publish command.

Comment: Fantastic! It just worked fine. Such a relief now, cheers.

Comment: Where to remove `--output` from? I have a similar problem.