# Microsoft.CodeAnalysis build failing despite project locally running correctly

Tags: azure-devops, build, code-analysis, pull-request, microsoft.codeanalysis

I am getting an error upon build in Azure DevOps when trying to merge to develop:

> ##[error]CSC(0,0): Error CS0006: Metadata file '..\packages\Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Analyzers.1.0.0\analyzers\dotnet\cs\Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Analyzers.dll'
> could not be found
> ##[error]CSC(0,0): Error CS0006: Metadata file '..\packages\Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Analyzers.1.0.0\analyzers\dotnet\cs\Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Analyzers.dll' could not be found

I had this error in my Visual Studio when building the solution as well but I reinstalled CodeAnalysers and it had gone.

It is an Umbraco project (7.15.3) so it is using version 1.0.0 Analysers.

I do not understand why it is failing on build in DevOps if it's compiling correctly on my local?

The build step is shows this config in YAML:

```
steps:
- task: VSBuild@1   displayName: 'Build solution'   inputs:
    solution: '$(Parameters.solution)'
    msbuildArgs: '/p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:WebPublishMethod=Package /p:PackageAsSingleFile=true /p:SkipInvalidConfigurations=true
/p:PackageLocation="$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)\\"'
    platform: '$(BuildPlatform)'
    configuration: '$(BuildConfiguration)'
```

Can anyone help please?

Comment: You can try the [workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64352989/11508192) given in this case with the same problem to see if it helps.

Comment: I don't get where to remove `--output` from? I can't see it in YAML part on the 'Build solution' step or in any other step. I don't even have `arguments` property there - I have added my build configuration to the question @Hugh